# Horizontal selection slider in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal selection slider that can be used inside a contact form in order to select a desired amount of money. I have produced a prototype of what I want but whenever I try to replicate it in HTML/CSS, no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Prototype: https://i.gyazo.com/acabda5c81a19686a2ae0f7201314c11.mp4

Obviously, I want just the text inside the rounded box to move, not the whole page that is just because I built it inside AdobeXD.

I can't provide any working code since I haven't even managed to achieve anything near what I am hoping for. I have looked around Google as well and couldn't find anything referring to a 'horizontal selection box' (o.e.)

I am looking just for a steer in the right direction, I don't want the full code to be written for me.

(JavaScript tag added since I assume it will be needed)

Answer (score 0):

I would use Javascript to create a button click event with left and right (up and down) as an argument. Increment or decrement the variable based on the argument, and if the variable goes larger or smaller than the number of selections you have then “wrap” to the other side. Have a list of all your prices.

After you increment or decrement the variable, use that to reference the list and change the InnerHTML of the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic implementation of what you've described, that you can take further.

There are three main keys in the method I've implemented this effect in:

1. The idea is that - at any moment - all the elements preceding the visible element have class `hiddenLeft`, while all the ones that are after it have class `hiddenRight`.
2. The `overflow: hidden` CSS property, which hides the "hidden" items.
3. The `transform: translateX()` CSS properties, which allow the `transition` to animate the items accordingly.
   When the classes `hiddenLeft/hiddenRight` are added to an element, it transitions in the relevant direction. When they're removed, the element transitions back to the centre of the box, hence to the visible area.

```js
var current = 1;
const initial = 1;

// Initialization
const contentItems = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonContent');
for (let i = 0; i < contentItems.length; i ++) {
  if (i < initial) {
    contentItems[i].classList.add('hiddenLeft');
  }
  else if (i > initial) {
    contentItems[i].classList.add('hiddenRight');
  }
}

function move(direction) {
  if (direction < 0 && current < contentItems.length - 1) {
    contentItems[current].classList.add('hiddenLeft');
    contentItems[current + 1].classList.remove('hiddenRight');
    current++;
  } else if (direction > 0 && current > 0) {
    contentItems[current].classList.add('hiddenRight');
    contentItems[current - 1].classList.remove('hiddenLeft');
    current--;
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between
}

.button {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonContent {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.hiddenLeft {
  transform: translateX(-200px);
}

.hiddenRight {
  transform: translateX(200px);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="leftButton" class="button" onclick="move(-1)">&#60;</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="buttonContent">red</div>
    <div class="buttonContent">green</div>
    <div class="buttonContent">blue</div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightButton" class="button" onclick="move(1)">&#62;</div>
</div>
```